# GridApi.setFilterModel ag-grid not working properly

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-ng2

I have following code

```
onGridReady = (event: GridReadyEvent) => {     
   this.gridApi.setFilterModel(init.filterModel);
}
```

`init.filterModel`- it is object with 2 keys after setFilterModel executed
in `this.gridApi.getFilterModel()` there's only one key instead of two key.

but in this variant

```
onGridReady = (event: GridReadyEvent) => {
    this.gridApi.setFilterModel(init.filterModel); // sleep(1ms)     
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1)).then(() => {   } 
}
```

`gridApi.getFilterModel()` returns valid result, how it can be solved without this hack?

`gridApi.getFilterModel()` returns valid result, how it can be solved without this hack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to spot your exact problem without more details but let's give it a shot

Modify your onGridReady event like the following

```
onGridReady: (params) => {
  var filterModel = params.api.getFilterModel();
  console.log('filterModel first', filterModel);
},
```

and your onFirstDataRendered event like the following

```
onFirstDataRendered: (params) => {
  var hardcodedFilter = {
    country: {
      type: 'set',
      values: ['Ireland', 'United States'],
    },
    age: { type: 'lessThan', filter: '30' },
    athlete: { type: 'startsWith', filter: 'Mich' },
    date: { type: 'lessThan', dateFrom: '2010-01-01' },
  };
  params.api.setFilterModel(hardcodedFilter);

  filterModel = params.api.getFilterModel();
  console.log('filterModel last', filterModel);
},
```

Result:

[image: Result]

As you see, the first state of our filterModel object is different from its last state, no need to wait between using a promise.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/hh4DRg6LD3XwsrZR?preview

*NOTE:* I have used plain javascript here, you may need to modify it a little bit if you use a framework

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, on the screen that you provided there's no key 'country' can you check this?